# Can I force the increment value on scroll for dijit.form.NumberSpinner?

Tags: html, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using the `dijit.form.NumberSpinner()` widget in a form for looking up indexed content. This works great in most cases—entering a number, using the arrow keys, and using the spinner buttons all respond in the right manner. However, on some browsers (notably Firefox), using the scroll wheel over the field increments the value by something > 1.

Is there a way to force the scroll increment on such a number field to be 1 across all browsers? The +3/-3 behavior is strongly undesirable for my application as the results are scrolled through in real time as the value is updated.

I am already using a custom widget derived from NumberSpinner so adding or over-riding a property should not be difficult if that is what is required, I just don't know what to change. The [docs only say the increment should be 1 for arrow keys](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/NumberSpinner.html#dijit-form-numberspinner), they don't say anything about scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases it is best to leave the behavior of such widgets alone. The mouse wheel action taken will be familiar to the users of each browser as the stock input widgets respond the same way.

In the event that over-riding this does make sense, you can tweak the `adjust()` method of the dijit widget. If you want to force the widget to step through every intermediate value no matter size adjustment was requested, you can force the delta value to be 1, then proceed with the contents of the original function.

```
    adjust: function (val, delta) {
        delta = delta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        return this.inherited(arguments);
    }
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rSLe/3/))

Thanks to [Dimitri M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492020/313192) for putting me onto the hunt, but I found overriding the value in `adjust()` to be simpler than re-defining `_mouseWheeled()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it depends on what the event itself provides (= given by the browser). Currently it uses either the `evt.wheelDelta` or `evt.detail` property from the **mousewheel** event to determine the increment value. However, there are no standards yet and most implementations are using certain functions to normalize the scrolling speed.

If you use the following code in Firefox:

```js
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/mouse", "dojo/on", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner", "dojo/parser"], function(ready, mouse, on, registry) {
    ready(function() {
        on(registry.byId("mySpinner").domNode, mouse.wheel, function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.detail);
        });
    });
});
```

It will show you that this value is `3` or `-3` when executed in Firefox.

If you really don't want it to depend on what the browser says, you can override the `_mouseWheeled` function:

```
FixedNumberSpinner = declare("dijit/form/FixedNumberSpinner", [ NumberSpinner ], {
    _mouseWheeled: function(/*Event*/ evt){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        var wheelDelta = evt.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        var detailDelta = evt.detail > 0 ? -1 : 1;
        var scrollAmount = evt.detail ? detailDelta : wheelDelta;
        if(scrollAmount !== 0){
            var node = this[(scrollAmount > 0 ? "upArrowNode" : "downArrowNode" )];
            this._arrowPressed(node, scrollAmount, this.smallDelta);
            if(this._wheelTimer){
                this._wheelTimer.remove();
            }
            this._wheelTimer = this.defer(function(){
                this._arrowReleased(node);
            }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

But please remember that the implementation might still change in the near future, so personally I would just stick with the increment of 3.

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZQTY/5/

---

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, an even easier solution would be to override the `adjust()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and this certainly works. I wonder howerever if this can't be simplified. In my application changing the value without stepping through every intermediate value makes basically no sense. Is there any reason I shouldn't achieve this by overriding the value being passed to the existing adjust function like so: `adjust: function(val, delta) { delta = delta > 0 ? 1 : -1; return this.inherited(arguments); }` as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rSLe/3/)?

Comment: O, that solution is even better. I didn't find it directly so I digged into the code and noticed this function, but overriding the `adjust` function is probably a lot better.